# Affect several DIVs on hover of one DIV of the same Parent

Tags: html, css

**Goal:** Hovering one box and all the other boxes fade out (opacity).

**Pen:** http://codepen.io/su1ts/pen/eJJbWm

**HTML:**

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner one">1</div>
  <div class="inner two">2</div>
  <div class="inner three">3</div>
  <div class="inner four">4</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.outer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.inner {
  width: 21%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  margin-right: 1%;
  float: left;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.inner:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.one:hover + .two + .three {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

I can't find a way to add more than one class on the .one:hover class.

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you could do this forwards, but not backwards. CSS tends to only allow inward / child-forward scanning; element 1 cannot ever change due to a state change of its sibling, element 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use javascript to control opacity

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.outer > .inner').mouseover(function(){
    $('.outer > .inner').css('opacity','0.5'); 
    $(this).css('opacity','1');  
  }).mouseout(function(){
    $('.outer > .inner').css('opacity','1');
  });
});
```

Example in
https://jsfiddle.net/rboschini/958za7kf/

Comment: This works perfectly and was exactly what I was looking for. JS for the win! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: May the jQuery Force be with you